# Migration to androidx.databinding on AndroidStudio 3.0

Tags: data-binding, android-studio-3.0, androidx

I'd like to ask if it's possible to migrate to androidx.databinding in AndroidStudio 3.0. 
I don't want to upgrade to AndroidStudio 3.2 just yet, and it seems that I can only import android.databinding instead of the androidx version.

I have added this in my app gradle file:

```
kapt "androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.2.0-alpha16"
```

Project gradle dependency:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
```

All the other androidx libraries I added on gradle can be imported in code, but not databinding. Has anyone here still using AndroidStudio 3.0 successfully used androidx.databinding?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

In the app build.gradle, I updated the dependency from -jre8 to -jdk8:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```

This is the app build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

    // architecture components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:$rootProject.pagingVersion"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"

    kapt "androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.2.1"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    }
}
```

And this is the project build.gradle versions:

```
ext {
    archLifecycleVersion = '2.0.0'
    roomVersion = '2.1.0-alpha02'
    pagingVersion = '2.1.0-beta01'

    supportLibVersion = '1.0.0'
}
```

I executed this to find out more about the issue on my project:

./gradlew :app:kaptDebugKotlin

and I got this error:

```
e: error: cannot access NonNull
  class file for android.support.annotation.NonNull not found
  Consult the following stack trace for details.
  com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for android.support.annotation.NonNull not found
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open_utf8([BI)V
        at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open_utf8(Native Method)
        at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open(NativeDB.java:71)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.open(DB.java:174)
        at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:220)
        at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:76)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:25)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:24)
        at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
        at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
        at androidx.room.verifier.DatabaseVerifier$Companion.create(DatabaseVerifier.kt:81)
```

So it seems that the underlying sqlite library is still using android.support.annotation.NonNull. Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks.